# AnyLogic: Total Delay Time in a discrete event simulation

Tags: delay, anylogic

Is there any function to measure the total delay time needed in an iteration of a DES? I want to do a Monte Carlo Experiment with my DES and iterate the DES 1000 times. Every iteration I want to measure the total delay time needed in this iteration and plot it to a histogram. I have already implemented aMonteCarlo Experiment. My idea was to have a variable `totalDelayTime` and instantiate this variable with the total delay time needed in every iteration. In my monte carlo experiment I want to plot this variable via a histogram. Is there any solution or simple anylogic function to measure/get the total delay time? I tried to call my variable `totalDelayTime` in the sink and said: `totalDelayTime = time()`. But when trace this variable via `traceln(totalDelayTime)`to the console I get the exact same delay time for any iteration. However, when I just write `traceln(time())` in the sink, I get other delay times for every iteration.

Comment: By total delay time you mean total simulation run time? Or total delay of an agent within a system?

Comment: I mean the Total simulation run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the total simulation run time by calling `time()` in the "On destroy" code box of `Main`. It returns the total time in the model time units.

If you need it in a special unit, call `time(MINUTE)` or similar.